# unique_ptr becomes empty after moving

Tags: c++

I'm trying for the first time to use unique_ptr to grow a binary tree, which basically works like the following:

```
void growTree(unique_ptr<Node> root){
//do some calculations
root->value = "some value"
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            unique_ptr<Node> child(new Node);
            growTree(move(child));
            root->children.push_back(move(child));
    }
    }
```

However, I found that the pointer "child" becomes empty before I push them back to `root->children`. Why does it lose its values after the recursion? What am I doing wrong here? Thank you!

EDIT1: Now I realized that I can't use the unique_ptr to get the expected value after moving it, so how can I do it (grow a tree) with a smart pointer?

Comment: The unique thing is no longer in one hand if you move it into the other hand. That seems to be working as intended.

Comment: `growTree(move(child))` indeed leaves child empty, so why would it not be empty on the next line?

Comment: " unique_ptr becomes empty after moving " - Yeees. What else would you expect from a *unique*_ptr??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's perfectly normal:

Before the `push_back`, you are moving `child` with `std::move`. It literally means that you are giving away `child` to `growTree`, you don't want it anymore.

After the move, `child` is no longer pointing to the original object (because another object has the pointer to it, you moved it after all).

---

If you want to modify `child`, you should pass it as a *reference*, so that `growTree` can modify the the `Node` `child` points to, without the `child` losing the pointer to it:

```
void growTree(std::unique_ptr<Note>& node);
```

Answer (score 2):

After you move from an object it is conceptually empty. This is why moving can be more efficient than copying, because you can steal resources which are then gone. Moving from an object twice without giving is a new value is a bug. Additionally a `unique_ptr` has unique ownership of an object, consequently there can only be one, so you cannot pass it to both `growTree` and `root->children`.

To solve the issue you must decide who owns the `child`. `std::move` the child there and keep a stable reference to that place in the other place. If the place is runtime dependent you can use a `shared_ptr` instead.

Answer (score 1):

When you move something to someone else you no longer have the moved-from stuff. Why would you expect that?

Once you move the unique_ptr into the growTree call, the original object is now in a valid but empty state (other objects would often be in a valid but unspecified state and certainly not the original state and should *not* be used again).
This is expected and your code is buggy due to trying to use it again.

Comment: *"valid but indeterminate state"* -- The state of `unique_ptr` is not indeterminate after it has been moved from. It is null, and you are free to use it again.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley The standard says, and I quote "Objects of types defined in the C++ standard library may be moved from (12.8). Move operations may be explicitly specified or implicitly generated. Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall be placed in a valid but unspecified state.".

Comment: The term used by e.g. cppreference is *valid but unspecified state* and is explained as *That is, only the functions without preconditions, such as the assignment operator, can be safely used on the object after it was moved from*

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Exactly, "unless otherwise specified". It is specified for `unique_ptr`, in 20.10.1/4 -- *note edit, it's chapter 20, not 2*

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley my bad. It is empty, I missed that.